# How to test if certain assemblies have been loaded into memory?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have some code that uses the Crystal Reports runtime libraries to generate and discard a small dummy report, in order to ensure that the libraries are loaded into memory in good time before the user creates a genuine report. (It's a 'perceived performance' issue.) The performance has been notably improved when the user generates a report, so that clearly all works.

Now I need to write a unit test that proves that the Crystal libraries have indeed been loaded into memory when expected - however my attempts to test what is there using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()` does not help. (`GetCallingAssembly().GetModules()` is no better either.)

How can I check from within my unit test to see if these assemblies have been loaded?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

The following code example uses the GetAssemblies method to get a list of all assemblies that have been loaded into the application domain. The assemblies are then displayed to the console.

```
public static void Main() 
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        //Provide the current application domain evidence for the assembly.
        Evidence asEvidence = currentDomain.Evidence;
        //Load the assembly from the application directory using a simple name. 

        //Create an assembly called CustomLibrary to run this sample.
        currentDomain.Load("CustomLibrary",asEvidence);

        //Make an array for the list of assemblies.
        Assembly[] assems = currentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        //List the assemblies in the current application domain.
        Console.WriteLine("List of assemblies loaded in current appdomain:");
            foreach (Assembly assem in assems)
                Console.WriteLine(assem.ToString());
    }
```

P.S. : To run this code example, you need to create an assembly named CustomLibrary.dll, or change the assembly name that is passed to the GetAssemblies method.

See here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx)

Comment: Is that any different in result to using the Process.GetModules() method?

Comment: this doesn't work anymore 
System.NotSupportedException: 'This method implicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.'

Comment: takes this instead 
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();